# Get element offset().top when elements are added and removed from the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` container element that can be at any position on the page. For example, a user might add my element halfway down the page, or 2/3's of the way down, or some arbitrary position. There will be content before/after/before & after it.

I need to get the `offset().top` of this but I find that this doesn't change. I have a `div` that prints a line at the point at which the offset is being calculated, but it's nowhere near the ACTUAL top of the div element.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The jQuery:

```
var elementPos;
$(window).load(function () {
  // Store the offset
  elementPos= $('.elementPosWrapper').offset().top;
});
```

The basic html:

```
<div class="elementPosWrapper" id="elementPosWrapper">
  ...
</div>
```

With other div elements that may be added before/after this. I just need to have the actual top value of the element be accurate, whether the page is 10,000px or 2,000px high.

Comment: If you don't post the code we will have no clue on what your HTML will look like, what factors are affecting the results and what mistake you are making in the code

Comment: I'll post the jquery I am using @RajshekarReddy

Comment: using my mind reading skills I would say you have calculated the offset at the wrong time... code please: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE].

Comment: I have added what I believe to be the relevant code @Pete, thanks.

Comment: `$('.elementPosWrapper')` returns an array so make sure you are getting the correct element. if you are only expecting one element with that then use `.eq(0).offset().top`

Comment: what others properties have the `div elementPosWrapper`? Is draggable, droppable?.